# C++ Reading everything after specific line in char

Tags: c++, char

I have a char like this

```
    char buff[1024]
```

Then i have alot of stuff in that buff. But i want everything after these \r\n\r\n

So if the char looks like this

```
    "asdfEianfd\r\n\r\ndsakfmagnrgsginagres"
```

I would like to recieve the output

```
    dsakfmagnrgsginagres
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, this isn't really the C++ way, since you already have it in a `char` array, but let's do it C-style anyway:

```
const char* phrase = "\r\n\r\n";
char *remain = strstr(buff, phrase);
if( remain != NULL ) remain += strlen(phrase);
```

Now, provided that the newline pattern was found, `remain` will now point to the start of the text you're looking for.  If the pattern was not found, `remain` will be NULL.

This will only find the *first* occurrence of the pattern (`"\r\n\r\n"`) and return everything that follows.  If you actually want to pull out lines, you will have to do forward searches and tokenise manually, or look at something like `strtok` (which is a bit over-simplified).

Comment: @NikBougalis This code finds the location in `buff` of the text `"\r\n\r\n"`, then gives a pointer to the character that follows it - hence the rest of the string.  In this case, `strlen(phrase)` is 4.  I didn't show `buff`, which obviously contains a longer string.

Comment: Never mind - stupid comment deleted. I read that as `+= strlen(buff)` for some reason.